# The LinearLayout returned is null in the subclass of PreferenceActivity

Tags: android

I have a SettingsActivity which is a subclass of PreferenceActivity in my library project

The oncreate method looks like this

```
addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.preferences);
setContentView(R.layout.main);
```

The preference.xml file has structure like element PreferenceScreen -> PreferenceCategory -> Preference 
My main main.xml Looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:orientation="vertical">


  <!--Listview will be replaced by preferences  -->

  <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The above class SettingsActivity is subclassed in another project and Looks like this

```
public class SettingsActivityFree extends SettingsActivity 
{
       private AdView adView;

       @Override
   protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
       {        
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

            //...

            // layout returned will be null ..
            LinearLayout layout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.main);

            // Add the adView to it
            layout.addView(adView);
       }
```

The problem is I am trying to get LinearLayout from the parent class so that I can add my stuff in it, but for some reason it returns null , the reason I have LinearLyout in the SettingsActivity class is because I want to put some ads etc at the top of preferences and without putting ad specific code in the Library project

Please advise If I am missing something here,

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to give your LinearLayout an `id` using `android:id="@+id/whatever"`. Then you can search for it using `findViewById(R.id.whatever)`.

Answer (score 0):

You should really check the developer site. You are not doing it correctly. Look up the documentation on ListView and ListActivity. Learn how it works before using it.

Also as a hint:

You don't do this `(LinearLayout)findViewById(R.layout.main);`

When retrieving a view, you will find it in `R.id.(whatever)` not in `R.layout.(whatever)`